# Determining Ribbon Location Name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, ribbon

I am somewhat new to SharePoint and needing some assistance. I am using SP 2013 and I've managed to add a new icon to a Ribbon for the `Ribbon.ListItem` ribbon with no problem and it works beautifully.

However, now I am trying to do the same with a ribbon I am unsure of the name of. The ribbon appears at the top of a record in a list when you click on the record/item to view the details of it. (Viewing the details of an individual record) Image shown here with the area in yellow I am trying to add the new icon to.

[image: View Item Details Ribbon]

I am on SharePoint 2013 Foundation, and using SharePoint Designer to attempt to add the icon, as shown in the screenshot below. (Ignore the ribbon name I have in there, I was attempting to troubleshoot it).

[image: Create Custom Action Image SharePoint Designer]

Any help/direction you could lend me would be most appreciated. I have been through all the old posts here related to my ask and have been unable to find a clear answer/direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look's like you are in a list form. So, the location is:

```
Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children
```

Without knowing the Sequence Numbers being used in that ribbon, you will have to do a little trial and error testing. (I'm sure it is documented somewhere on the web.) "100" should put your Custom Action to the right of the Edit Item button.

You can discover the locations using the browser's F12 tools. (This is from Firefox.)

[image]

Comment: Ah I see... I had gotten the name of it prior but was still unable to make it display. After you answered, it finally clicked with me what the issue was. In SharePoint Designer under Custom Actions, I was adding the incorrect Custom Action. The dropdown has choices from List Item, Display Form, Edit Form, New Form and View Ribbon. I was picking View Ribbon and supplying what you had provided, which of course was not working. Once I picked Display Form, it started working beautifully. Thank you for your help!!!!